# openwhisk postdeploy fails on single node ubuntu virtual machine

Tags: nginx, docker, openwhisk

I am trying to run openwhisk serverless framework on a single node ubuntu vm.

I am following the instructions [here](https://github.com/openwhisk/openwhisk/tree/master/tools/ubuntu-setup).

I followed the instructions for database set up and then went over to the steps listed for ansible single node: (`ansible/README.md`)

Using the steps under "Deploy Using CouchDB", in the following step:
`ansible-playbook -i environments/<environment> postdeploy.yml`

I get an error in running installCatalog.sh

Looks like the URL 172.17.0.1 is not accesible. Where am I going wrong?

```
TASK [install the catalog from the catalog location] ***************************
Thursday 04 May 2017  10:41:29 +0000 (0:00:01.602)       0:00:09.063 ********** 
fatal: [ansible]: FAILED! => {"changed": true, "cmd": "./installCatalog.sh /home/techie/openwhisk/ansible/../ansible/files/auth.whisk.system 172.17.0.1 /whisk.system /home/techie/openwhisk/ansible/../bin/wsk", "delta": "0:00:01.840405", "end": "2017-05-04 10:41:32.380241", "failed": true, "rc": 7, "start": "2017-05-04 10:41:30.539836", "stderr": "error: Package update failed: Put 172.17.0.1/api/v1/namespaces/_/packages/websocket?overwrite=true: dial tcp 172.17.0.1:443: getsockopt: connection refused\nerror: Package update failed: Put 172.17.0.1/api/v1/namespaces/_/packages/combinators?overwrite=true: dial tcp 172.17.0.1:443: getsockopt: connection refused\nerror: Package update failed: Put 172.17.0.1/api/v1/namespaces/_/packages/watson-speechToText?overwrite=true: dial tcp 172.17.0.1:443: getsockopt: connection refused\nerror: Package update failed: Put 172.17.0.1/api/v1/namespaces/_/packages/utils?overwrite=true: dial tcp 172.17.0.1:443: getsockopt: connection refused\nerror: Package update failed: 
.......
```

I ran docker ps after the deployment step. There were several dockers like zookeeper, kafka, etc. running. Is there supposed to be a nginx docker running too? In my set-up there was no nginx docker running.

In the config files, I have base url set to 172.17.0.1 - is this ok, or could it be something else?

Comment: `getsockopt: connection refused` indicates that the edge router (nginx) is not running. `docker ps -a | grep nginx` will show you the failed container on which you can do `docker logs` to see why it failed to startup.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I too suspected that nginx didn't come up. but can't find nginx docker either doing docker ps or docker ps -a. Is the build step (gradlew distDocker) supposed to create it? Or is it any of the steps under ansible/README.md?

Answer (score 0):

I found that I needed to also run `edge.yml` after `apigateway.yml` and before `postdeploy.yml` to get the postdeploy script to work and then to be able to have the `wsk` tool work against the API endpoint.